# Prove directly from the definition of mapping that h is differentiable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Hey guys I'm going through some problems on my own, currently going through both chapter 2 and chapter 3 of *Advanced calculus of several variables* by C.H. Edwards. Anyway I'm having problems with problem 2.9... I'll copy and paste the problem since its the easiest way:

If $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ are both differentiable at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove directly from the definition that the mapping $h \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m+k}$, defined by $h(x) = (f(x),g(x))$, is differentiable at $a$.

I know its looked down here of posting the exact question, but I'm pretty lost and I'm learning this stuff on my own. This book is a lot more advanced than my book from calc 3 lol... Any hints or full solutions appreciated... thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a mapping $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $a$, a linear map $D \phi(a)$ exists such that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\|h\|<\delta$, then $\|\phi(a+h)-\phi(a) - D \phi(a) h\| \leq \epsilon \|h\|$.

Now consider $h$ above. First, we guess at the form of the derivative, and since $h=(f,g)$, we would guess that the derivative has the form $Dh(a) = (Df(a), Dg(a))$, and when operating on $\eta$, would be $Dh(a) \eta = (Df(a) \eta, Dg(a) \eta)$. Second, we need a norm for the combined object (ie, a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{m+k}$). All norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, so we can choose a norm that makes life easier for us. In this case, we will choose $\|(x,y) \|_* = \max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$.

So, let $\epsilon>0$, and let $\delta_f, \delta_g >0$ be the relevant $\delta$s for $f,g$. Let $\delta = \min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$, and $\|\eta\|< \delta$. Then we have $\|f(a+\eta)-f(a) - D f(a) \eta\| \leq \epsilon \|\eta\|$ and $\|g(a+\eta)-g(a) - D g(a) \eta\| \leq \epsilon \|\eta\|$. Then we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\|h(a+\eta)-h(a) - D h(a) \eta\|_* &=& \|(f(a+\eta)-f(a),g(a+\eta)-g(a)) - (Df(a) \eta, Dg(a) \eta)\|_* \\
&=&  \max(\|f(a+\eta)-f(a) - Df(a) \eta\|, \|g(a+\eta)-g(a) - Dg(a) \eta\|) \\
&\leq& \epsilon \|\eta\|
\end{eqnarray}
Hence $h$ is differentiable, with derivative $(Df(a), Dg(a))$.

Comment: thanks... i'm terrible at delta epsilon proofs. Do you have any tips on how to get better with them? I'm more more used to applied math over proofs.

Comment: For me it was lots & lots of practice. Generally, I prefer to stay away from $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs where possible, and rely on formula or encapsulating results if I can. That said, detailed analysis at the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ level can provide tremendous insight (such as results in Kantorovich & Akilov's "Functional analysis") that is glossed over by more abstract results.